# Method missing in Java or PHP

Tags: java, php, ruby

I have been looking at different languages to get started. I found method_missing in Ruby very interesting but was not able to find the same in Java and PHP. 
Is there something like method_missing in Java or PHP ?

Comment: After using ruby for a long time and going back to Java, I feel like going back to 20th century.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP has `__call($name, array $args)`. It is a catchall which handles situations where you call a method which is not defined for the instance.

In PHP >= 5.3 there is also `__callStatic($name, array $args)` which functions largely the same way only on the class level (duh).

```
class MyClass
{
    public function __call($name, array $args)
    {
        echo "You tried to call $name(".implode(',',$args)."). Silly user.";
    }
}

$k = new MyClass();
$k->doSomething(1,2,3); // You tried to call doSomething(1,2,3). Silly user.
```

The equivalent in Java is a bit more cumbersome and it involves something called the [Proxy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class. A tutorial can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html) -- the examples are a bit much to summarize here.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you might be able to do something with an interface, a [Proxy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) and reflection.

Comment: Method missing is not meaning check whether a method exists.

Comment: there is a respond_to?(:method_name) for checking if a method exist for an object in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, you can use the magic method `__call()` .